# Use the shell method to fine the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by:

Tags: calculus, integration

$y=12x-11, y=\sqrt{x}$, and $x=0$.

I know I will be using $V=2\pi\int (\sqrt{x})^2-(12x-11)^2 dx$

It's the setting up of the problem I am having difficulty with. If anyone can help me without giving away the answer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What line (or axis) are you revolving that region around?

Comment: It seems like that we have the incomplete bounds.  Check [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+12x+-+11+and+y+%3D+%E2%88%9Ax+for+0+%E2%89%A4+x+%E2%89%A4+1).  There is no way to construct the volume like this.

Comment: Has the volume of the solid broken the law in any way?

Comment: @amWhy "Use the shell method to fine the volume..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks, from your title, as though you need to use the *cylindrical shell* method for finding the volume of revolution about (I'm assuming here) the $y$-axis. The work you show is more consistent with the disk method (except you'd use $\pi$ in that case).

With the shell method, since volume will be of the *cylinder* obtained when revolving the region, we need to use as factors:

- $2\pi$, since we revolve the region $360^\circ = 2\pi$ radians (all the way around the y-axis;
- the *radius of the "cylinder"* $r(x)$ which will be given simply by "$x$" (the distance of $x$ from the y-axis), and
- the height of the "cylinder" $h(x)$, which in this case will be the
  distance given between the "top curve" minus the "bottom curve". So height will be given by $$h(x) = [\sqrt x - (12x - 11)] = \sqrt x - 12x + 11.$$

One of our bounds of integration will be $x = 0$. The other will be when $x$ is equal to the x-coordinate at which the two curves $y = \sqrt x$ and $y = 12x - 11$ intersect. This will be at $x = 1$. (Recall, we can solve for the $x$ of intersection(s) by equating the two curves: $\sqrt x = 12x - 11$. We can square both sides to get a quadratic equation, solve for the roots, and throw out the negative value. Please confirm that the curves intersect at $(1, 1)$.)

This gives us the following integral to evaluate: $$\int_0^1 2\pi\, r(x) \,h(x)\,dx = 2\pi\int_0^1 x(\sqrt x - 12x + 11)\,dx$$

Comment: I got from there x^3/2-4x^3+11/2x^2 then integrate to get 2π(5/2π)=5π

Comment: First expand the integrand: $\int (x^{3/2} - 12x^2 + 11 x)\,dx$. Then integrate: $2\pi(\dfrac {2x^{5/2}}{5} - 4x^3 + \dfrac {11x^2}{2}) = 2\pi(\dfrac{2}{5} - 4 + \dfrac {11}{2})\Big|_0^1$.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong there. Alright final answer 19π/5 :)Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's the answer I obtained too! You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my dear friend. I know you are asleep right now and hope you have a nice and colorful sleep. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are revolving the region around the y-axis.
If that is the case, you want to find $\int_0^1 2\pi r(x)h(x) dx$, where
r(x) is the distance from a typical vertical line segment to the y-axis and h(x) is the height of a typical vertical line segment.